# Finding the Height and line equation of a plain

Tags: analytic-geometry

1. Create the equation of the median and the height From A where ABC is a triangle, find the angle between median and the height from A.

$$A(2, 0); B(1, -2), C(3, 6)$$

*Solution:*

If M is the middle point between A and C it has cordinates M(2, 2). The equation of the median can be found with:

$$(x-M1)/(M1-A1) = (y-M2)/(M2-A2)$$
$$0y=2x-4$$

```
How can I get the height AH ?
```

2. Create the equation of the sides of a triangle ABC if it's given *B(1, -2)* and the height *h: x + 4y -2 =0* and the median *m : x = 2 *. h is the height which comes from B, m is median which comes from B:

*Solution:*

```
How do we solve this one ?
```

3. Create the equation of the plain a, containing the points *A(4, -1, 0)*; *B(2, 1, 2)*; * C(6, 3, 2) *  and the line l which goes through the points M(2, -3, 4) and N(3, -5, 7).

*Solution:*

```
How do we solve this one ?
```

4. make a equation of the plain a containing

$$l1: x = λ +3; y = −λ; z = λ$$
$$l2 : x = µ +1; y = −µ; z = µ +4$$

and find the projection of the line $$l:x = 2t+1; y = t +1 ; z = 3t+1$$ on a

*Solution:*

```
How do we solve this one ?
```

PS. Sorry for the bad MathJax and the dumb question

Comment: These should be four separate questions.

Comment: I can post a question once every 40 minutes, and these questions are quite related

Comment: Only insofar as they all look like they came from the same homework assignment.